# django-admin.py is blocked by exporting myapp.settings

Tags: django, django-admin

I've exported some settings by mistake, like:
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=example.settings

Now when i try to use django-admin.py it gives me error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
management.execute_from_command_line()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
 utility.execute()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
commands = get_commands()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
% (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
 ImportError: Could not import settings 'example.settings.base' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named example.settings.base
```

I've found command called flush, but django-admin is blocked and i don't know what to do, probably i need to find sys.path file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you export settings?  If you just did the command you typed from bash, if you restart your terminal (i.e. close xterm and reopen), you should be reset.  Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: thanks, restarting terminal works